# Write program to compute & print average of the numbers in a text file, which include both text and numbers using two higher-order functions

Tags: python

How to write program that computes and prints the average of the numbers in a text file, which include both text and numbers using two higher-order functions?

Input of text file is like:

```
Age of ram is 40.his fathers age is 90.he has 4 cars, & 8 two wheelers.
```

I have to find average of the integers value present here, ignoring the alphabet.

I tried it for other file simply containg integers not the alphabets

```
import functools

file = open("integers.txt", 'r')
file = file.read()

file = file.split()

file = list(map(int, file))

print(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y / len(file), file, 0))
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have? Please show a [mre].

Comment: Sir, I have problem while ignoring the text in a file, &calculating average for a number, thanks for your kind support sir, looking for your help please

Comment: And **what** is the problem? Please read the article I've linked and include a specific example in your question.

Comment: Describe the format of your input file.

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
text = 'Age of ram is 40.his fathers age is 90.he has 4 cars, & 8 two wheelers.'
# Replace other characters with space and join them
# Split to get numbers
number_txt = ''.join([c if c.isdigit() else ' ' for c in text]).split()
# Convert number text to int
numbers = list(map(int, number_txt))
# Find average
avg = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

Comment: This will interpret 40 as two numbers, 4 and 0. I'm not sure if this is the goal.